# Embed Google drawing in a Github wiki

Tags: github, google-docs, wiki

Is there a way to embed a public Google drawing in a GitHub wiki. I would prefer not save embed a png file but instead have a link to a living dokument.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. The image is probably your only approach.

Answer (score 7):

I published the Google drawing: File -> Publish to Web -> Link ... and then used the link as the image url, ie:

`![resources](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1zJ4.../pub?w=691&h=431)`

...and it seems to work ok. Changes to the drawing are updated in the Github wiki page when the page is refreshed.

Comment: Perfectly reasonable solution if the image content can be public.

Comment: Clever solution. I confirm this works for me as well, and changes update on refresh

Answer (score 7):

Replace edit at the end of the drawing URL with export/png and use it as the path to your image.

For example, if the drawing URL is https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/drawings/d/12345/edit, use this HTML image syntax:

```
<img src="https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/12345/export/png"
alt="image alt text"/>
```

You can do the same thing in Markdown:

```
![drawing](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/12345/export/png)
```

[source](https://github.com/evbacher/gd2md-html/wiki/Google-Drawings-by-reference)

Comment: eXACtLy what I was looking for, this should get a 100 upvotes! Where did you find that BTW? Because all of the other googel docs is /export?format=whatever, where did you find out that its /export/png ?

Answer (score 3):

GitHub wiki works on [markdown](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/) format. It doesn't support embedding of google drawings.

The best way to embed the drawing is inserting a png image with markdown and pointing it to a link.

```
[![Image-alt](image-url)](drawing-url)
```

Comment: Thanks that is what I am doing now. It would just have been nice to a a "live" document in my wiki