# Posting an image in c++ that is on google drawings

Tags: css, image

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41056959/embed-google-drawing-in-a-github-wiki) question as a reference, but, it dint went well...
The code im using is this one:

```css
body {
  background-image: url(' THIS IS WHAT IM TRYINA SOLVE HERE')
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  padding-top:10em;
}
```

Background-image isn't responding to the URL of the google drawing, what do I do to make the image appear?

Comment: Why don't you post the link you actually tried? Also, you are missing the `;` after the closing `)`.

Comment: yea, i added that, and the link is https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/e/2PACX-1vRmhOzg-YaseovffSsbypbEcJbz5KtCoSMVPqC5pOY1CY_GDGRF5NQzq5TNQKvN8TYPSnMhxIooSGb-/pub?w=1440&h=1080, this is for a website to show some drawings i made

Comment: now its in my drive, i can use this: <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WEfAPtyeOmZ6sNr8CG6YXWzKxJoLba1m/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>, now that i got that code, where should i place it?

Comment: That's an iframe and it's a private file so no one else can see it.

Comment: oh, alright....

Comment: i solved it!, i had to go and publish to the web the image in some source, but it doesnt seem right in the site, ill publish another question...